# PDO bindValue with \PDO::PARAM_BOOL causes statement execute to fail silently

Tags: php, mysql, pdo, doctrine-orm, prepared-statement

In one server setup I experience very strange error. There's PHP 5.3.6 with PDO Driver for MySQL, client library version 5.1.61. Everything is compiled by hand.

When I bind params with bindValue and set third parameter as \PDO::PARAM_BOOL then statement execute return false and nothing happens (no data inserted to MySQL, even no exception at all). When I don't use third parameter it goes well. In fact I can't ommit third parameter, bacues Doctrine2 DBAL sets it while converting parameters...

Here's code:

```
<?php
$pdo = new \PDO('mysql:host=***;dbname=***', '***', '***'); // hidden DB access
$pdo->setAttribute(\PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, \PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);

$stmt = $pdo->prepare('insert into outage (name, description, start_at, end_at, is_exception, extranet_id) values (?,?,?,?,?,?)');
$stmt->bindValue(1, 'Test name', \PDO::PARAM_STR);
$stmt->bindValue(2, 'Test desc', \PDO::PARAM_STR);
$stmt->bindValue(3, '2012-01-01 00:00:00', \PDO::PARAM_STR);
$stmt->bindValue(4, null, \PDO::PARAM_NULL);
$stmt->bindValue(5, false, \PDO::PARAM_BOOL);
$stmt->bindValue(6, 2, \PDO::PARAM_INT);
var_dump(array('stmt result' => ($result = $stmt->execute()), 'last insert id' => $pdo->lastInsertId(), 'stmt err code' =>  $stmt->errorCode(), 'pdo err code' =>  $pdo->errorCode()));
```

Result:

```
array(4) {
  ["stmt result"]=>
  bool(false)
  ["last insert id"]=>
  string(1) "0"
  ["stmt err code"]=>
  string(5) "00000"
  ["pdo err code"]=>
  string(5) "00000"
}
```

What possibly could go wrong? I've tried it on other 4 servers and didn't get this bug. Also if I pass '0' (as a string) to `$stmt->bindValue(5, false, \PDO::PARAM_BOOL);` it works good.

Comment: OK, problem is solved under PHP 5.3.10 on this server (Red Hat 5.4)

Answer (score 16, accepted):

I had the same problem on Ubuntu with PHP 5.3.10. (Interestingly there was no problem on windows with wamp...)

Actually it's a known bug in pdo: https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=38546

I use PDO::PARAM_INT instead of PDO::PARAM_BOOL. It works well, and you do not have to convert booleans to string like above.