# PDO Invalid Boolean Parameter

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I am trying to update my table using the following:

```
$stmt = $db->prepare("
    UPDATE Business SET
        Business.Name = ?,
        Business.Phone = ?,
        Business.Fax = ?,
        Business.Address = ?,
        Business.City = ?,
        Business.StateId = ?,
        Business.Zip = ?,
        Business.Referral = ?,
        Business.IsRemindedWeekly = ?,
        Business.DeletedOn = ?
    WHERE
        Business.BusinessId = ?");

// Execute the query
$stmt->execute(array(
    $_POST["Name"],
    $_POST["Phone"],
    $_POST["Fax"],
    $_POST["Address"],
    $_POST["City"],
    $_POST["StateId"],
    $_POST["Zip"],
    $_POST["Referral"],
    $_POST["IsRemindedWeekly"],
    ($_POST["DeletedOn"] && $_POST["DeletedOn"] != "0000-00-00" ? $_POST["DeletedOn"] : null),
    $_POST["BusinessId"]
));
```

And my schema looks like this:

```
CREATE TABLE `business` (
  `BusinessId` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `Name` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `Phone` char(10) DEFAULT NULL,
  `Fax` char(10) DEFAULT NULL,
  `Address` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `City` varchar(64) DEFAULT NULL,
  `StateId` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `Zip` char(5) DEFAULT NULL,
  `Signature` blob DEFAULT NULL,
  `Referral` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `IsRemindedWeekly` bit(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT b'0',
  `DeletedOn` date DEFAULT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;
```

However, the IsRemindedWeekly column is always being set to 1 regardless of the value sent to the request. When inspecting the network tab the payload appears to be sending a String value of "1", but even if I change my parameterized value to:

```
($_POST["IsRemindedWeekly"] == "1" ? 1 : 0)
```

(notice the non-type comparison operator) but regardless, the value in my database is still 1 after update operation. Am I missing something?

**UPDATE**

I am a little upset that the thread was closed because I'm still having difficulties. I've decided to use `bindValue` but it still isn't working. I've tried:

```
// Passing a 1 or 0 with PARAM_INT always returns false
$stmt->bindValue(":isRemindedWeekly", ($_POST["IsRemindedWeekly"] == "1" ? 1 : 0), PDO::PARAM_INT);

// Passing a 1 or 0 with PARAM_BOOL always returns false
$stmt->bindValue(":isRemindedWeekly", ($_POST["IsRemindedWeekly"] == "1" ? 1 : 0), PDO::PARAM_BOOL);

// Passing a true or false with PARAM_INT always returns false
$stmt->bindValue(":isRemindedWeekly", $_POST["IsRemindedWeekly"], PDO::PARAM_INT);

// Passing a true or false with a PARAM_BOOL always returns true
$stmt->bindValue(":isRemindedWeekly", $_POST["IsRemindedWeekly"], PDO::PARAM_BOOL);
```

Comment: You can try setting 'true' /  'false' instead of a number, because PDO will cast every value as string, unless you bind each: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10242312/pdo-bindvalue-with-pdoparam-bool-causes-statement-execute-to-fail-silently

Comment: Have you looked at the alleged 'duplicate'? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24326283/php-pdo-bindparam-and-mysql-bit

Answer (score 0):

When it expects `PDO::PARAM_BOOL`, you probably should provide it with `boolean`:

```
$_POST["IsRemindedWeekly"] == "1" // this evaluates to boolean
```

While it is generally easier to change the column to `TINYINT` and use `0` and `1`, because you'd have define the data-type for [bindValue()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.bindvalue.php) as `int $data_type = PDO::PARAM_BOOL`. This might be a matter of taste, because there is nothing wrong with either approach - but casting to `boolean` on read is less effort, than on write.

---

What you get from the `$_POST` will always be of data-type `string`.
eg. for `int` you'd have to type-cast: `(int) $_POST["IsRemindedWeekly"]`.

And you were missing the the type-cast to `boolean`, as I've suggested it above:

```
$stmt->bindValue(":isRemindedWeekly", $_POST["IsRemindedWeekly"] == "1", PDO::PARAM_BOOL);
```

Also see the PHP manual for [Type Juggling](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.type-juggling.php), which is quite essential.

Comment: Note that “`? true : false`” is superfluous and redundant.

Comment: @deceze Thanks for the hint, have corrected that.

Comment: @MartinZeitler I've posted an update, could you take a look at it.

Comment: @David Think I've found the mistake. And there's no need to be upset about having a duplicate closed. If you'd ask a duplicate `android` question, I'd probably act the same - but leaving a comment, at least.

Comment: @MartinZeitler I'm sorry for the late reply, but adding the comparison doesn't help either. It always returns a false value. I've even tried explicitly converting the post value to a Boolean as outlined in the type juggling documentation that you linked to and it returns the exact opposite result.